# GKE Ingress is slow to pick up pod readiness/liveness

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I managed to create a cluster using GKE using gce ingress successfully. However it takes a long time for Ingress to detect the service is ready (I already set both livenessProbe and readinessProbe).
My pods set up

```
Containers:
...
  gateway:
    Liveness:   http-get http://:5100/api/v1/gateway/healthz delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get http://:5100/api/v1/gateway/healthz delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
...
```

and ingress

```
...
Name:             main-ingress
  Host                              Path  Backends
  ----                              ----  --------
  <host>
                                    /api/v1/gateway/    gateway:5100 (<ip:5100>)
                                    /api/v1/gateway/*   gateway:5100 (<ip:5100>)
                                                        web:80 (<ip>)
Annotations:
  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:               {"k8s-be-***":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-***":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-***":"HEALTHY"}
  kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http:             false
```

What I notice is that if I killed all the service and redeploy, the backend stays at `UNHEALTHY` for quite some time before it picks it up even though Kubernetes itself managed to pick up that pods/service are all running

I also noticed that when `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe` is set, the Backend health check that's generated by ingress-gce is the following

```
Backend
Timeout: 30 seconds

Backend Health check
Interval: 70 seconds
Timeout: 1 second
Unhealthy threshold: 10 consecutive failures
Healthy threshold: 1 success
```

Whereas if I just deploy a simple nginx pod without specifying `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe`, the backend generated is the following

```
Backend
Timeout: 30 seconds

Backend Health Check
Interval: 60 seconds
Timeout: 60 seconds
Unhealthy threshold: 10 consecutive failures
Healthy threshold: 1 success
```

Is the Backend health check the root cause of the slowness of picking things up? If so, any idea how to speed it up?

---

**UPDATE**
Wanted to clarify after reading [@yyyyahir's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59374808/364569)

I understand that when creating new ingress it will take much longer because the ingress controller needs to provision the new Load Balancer, backend and all the other related things.

However what I also notice is that when I release a new version of the service (through Helm - deployment is set to Recreate rather than RollingUpgrade) OR if the pod is died (out of memory) and restarted, it takes quite a while before the backend status is healthy again despite the Pod is already in running/healthy state (this is with existing Ingress and Load Balancer in GCP). Is there a way to speed this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using GCE Ingress, you need to wait for the load balancer provisioning time before the [backend service](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service) is deemed as healthy.

Consider that when you use this ingress class, you're relying on the GCE infrastructure that automatically has to provision an [HTTP(S) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) and all of its components before sending requests into the cluster.

When you set up a deployment without `readinessProbe`, the default values are going to be applied to the load balancer health check:

```
Backend Health Check
Interval: 60 seconds
Timeout: 60 seconds
Unhealthy threshold: 10 consecutive failures
Healthy threshold: 1 success
```

However, using the `readinessProbe` [will add the `periodSeconds` value to the default health check configuration](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/69ae0fe59e6ab69d8865339fa096e4cb142309c4/pkg/backends/syncer.go#L224). So, in your case, you had `10` seconds + `60` by default = `70`.

```
Backend Health check
Interval: 70 seconds
Timeout: 1 second
Unhealthy threshold: 10 consecutive failures
Healthy threshold: 1 success
```

Note that GKE will only use `readinessProbe` to set the health check in the load balancer. Liveness is never picked.

This means that, the lowest value will always be that of the default load balancer health check, `60`. Since these values are automatically set when the load balancer is invoked from GKE, there is no way to change them.

Wrapping up, you have to wait for the load balancer provisioing period (around ~1-3 minutes) plus the `periodSeconds` value set in your `readinessProbe`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link to the code! I've tried to look at ingress-gce code but didn't manage to find it. I updated my question to clarify my question (which I missed earlier). Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I tried to replicate with the information you posted. I was continuously curling a working 3 replica deployment. I make it fail using 2 tests: First downscaling it to 0 and second updating it with a faulty image. Both immediately started to return 502s. I noticed that when I upscaled/redeployed a working image, it took around ~20 seconds to start serving requests normally (consider that no replica was healthy at that point). Is this what you're talking about? I also noticed that the web UI almost never picked the changes and took a long time to mark the BE as healthy/unhealthy, is this it?

Comment: Additionally, where are you seeing the error? How are you measuring this delay?

Comment: Yup, exactly as you described. I didn't really do a proper delay measurement but overall my experience is about ~1min before serving request normally. Not sure if anything can be done at this point to be honest

Comment: From all that information, seems like the variable here is the image deployed. If you set the minimal values for the readinessProbe, it might be related to the process in your own container, the [image pull policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images), [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) (if any), etc. Maybe the best way to address it would be checking there.

Comment: Right. Will look into it. Thanks!